# POST API request timeout issue

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest, http-post, resttemplate

I'm trying to make a POST API call to our external API via the API PROXY. I'm facing some timeout issues while making a API call. I used below restTemplate to make a API request. But at the same time I've implemented the retry for the template in case of any timeouts. I can avoid this issue by retrying that api request again.But I would like to find out the root cause for that to completely resolve the issue.Can anyone help me with this

**StackTrace:**

```
    org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on POST request for "https://localhost:8080/test": Operation timed out (Read failed); nested exception is java.net.SocketException: Operation timed out (Read failed)
```

```
 private static final int HTTP_CLIENT_RETRY_COUNT = 3;
        private static final int MAXIMUM_TOTAL_CONNECTION = 10;
        private static final int MAXIMUM_CONNECTION_PER_ROUTE = 5;
        private static final int CONNECTION_VALIDATE_AFTER_INACTIVITY_MS = 10 * 1000;
        public static RestTemplate createRestTemplate(int connectionTimeoutMs, int readTimeoutMs, ObjectMapper objectMapper) {
            HttpClientBuilder clientBuilder = HttpClients.custom();
            PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager connectionManager = new PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager();
            // Set the maximum number of total open connections.
            connectionManager.setMaxTotal(MAXIMUM_TOTAL_CONNECTION);
            // Set the maximum number of concurrent connections per route, which is 2 by default.
            connectionManager.setDefaultMaxPerRoute(MAXIMUM_CONNECTION_PER_ROUTE);
            connectionManager.setValidateAfterInactivity(CONNECTION_VALIDATE_AFTER_INACTIVITY_MS);
            clientBuilder.setConnectionManager(connectionManager);
            clientBuilder.setRetryHandler(new DefaultHttpRequestRetryHandler(HTTP_CLIENT_RETRY_COUNT, true, new ArrayList<>()) {
                @Override
                public boolean retryRequest(IOException exception, int executionCount, HttpContext context) {
                    LOGGER.info("Retry request, execution count: {}, exception: {}", executionCount, exception);
                    return super.retryRequest(exception, executionCount, context);
                }
            });
            HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory httpRequestFactory = new HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(clientBuilder.build());
            httpRequestFactory.setConnectTimeout(connectionTimeoutMs);
            httpRequestFactory.setConnectionRequestTimeout(readTimeoutMs);
            httpRequestFactory.setReadTimeout(readTimeoutMs);
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(httpRequestFactory);
            List<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor> interceptors = new ArrayList<ClientHttpRequestInterceptor>();
            interceptors.add(new LoggingRequestInterceptor());
            restTemplate.setInterceptors(interceptors);
            restTemplate.setRequestFactory(new BufferingClientHttpRequestFactory(httpRequestFactory));
            MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter messageConverter = restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream().filter(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance)
                    .map(MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter.class::cast).findFirst().orElseThrow(() -> new RuntimeException("MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter not found"));
            messageConverter.setObjectMapper(objectMapper);
            restTemplate.getMessageConverters().stream().filter(StringHttpMessageConverter.class::isInstance).map(StringHttpMessageConverter.class::cast).forEach(a -> {
                a.setWriteAcceptCharset(false);
                a.setDefaultCharset(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
            });
            return restTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Normally timeout issue mean that the connection could not be established. Have you tried to access that external API using any other client tools such as POSTMAN, curl, ...?  Or just ping to check whether you can access to that host.

Comment: @Hung CHu yes, I have tried. In local I'm not getting any issue. But when I deploy my code into Kubernetes Cluster. I'm facing issue.

Comment: Did you tried to test inside the container that your code is deployed? I think this issue might from the setting up with infra inside your kubernetes cluster

Comment: I have test everything looks fine.But this timeout issue happening only after every 10-15 transactions.

Comment: Then i think the issue might related to your network / infra config in your cluster. Does it have any firewall or rule that restrict your access?